# Help identifying Freewheel lockring

Tags: freewheel

I've recently acquired a retro steel bike which needs some work.
Has anyone ever seen a freewheel with this type of locking system? I haven't been able to find any tool which seems like it would be designed to open it. Note the splines are opposite from a normal lockring (ie: small gaps on the outside).
I've heard some older freewheel bikes have 'unremovable' freewheels- is this perhaps one of them?
There are no identifying marks or brand logos.

[image: Freewheel]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcbXT.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Uniglide. Cassette, not freewheel. The small cog is the lockring. Remove with two chainwhips.